# Testing mixed async/Promise-based code and callback-based code

Tags: mocha.js

This code:

```
it('should not say overspecified', async function (done) {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
    done();
});
```

Causes this:`Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.`

But...I'm not returning a Promise. I'm simply awaiting a promise.

If I change my code to this, it works:

```
it('should not say overspecified',function(){
  return new Promise(async resolve=>{
    await (new Promise(resolve=>resolve()));
    resolve();
  })
});
```

Why does it only work when I unnecessarily wrap my code in a Promise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This code:

```
it('should not say overspecified', async function (done) {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
    done();
});
```

> Causes this: *Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback or return a Promise; not both*.

Because `async functions` always [return a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), by design.

In Mocha, you can either return a `Promise` *or* use `done`, but *[not both](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)*.

I'd do it like this:

```
// Do not pass `done` as a parameter to `it` callback.
it('should not say over specified', function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve())
});
```

or if you want to use `await`:

```
// Do not pass `done` as a parameter to `it` callback.
it('should not say overspecified', async function () {
  await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
});
```

Here's a practical `async/await` example:

```
require('chai').should()

const getFoo = async () => 'foo'

describe('#getFoo()', () =>  {
  it('returns foo', async () => {
    const foo = await getFoo()
    foo.should.equal('foo')
  })
})
```

You should use `done` only for callback-based or event-based code.

It's completely unnecessary to use it with `Promise`-based code such as regular Promises or `async/await`.

### Testing mixed Promise and callback based code:

If I have control over the code that I'm testing (I wrote it), I "[promisify](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html)" all callback based code I use from external callback-style API's, so the entire asynchronous API of the code I'm working with always uses Promises. If sensibly used, then it obviously makes testing easier as well (by eliminating completely the need for done).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the explanation! I didn't realize that async functions returned Promises. In my test I'm actually doing something like `await thisMethod();setTimeout(1000,done);`. Here I'm mixing and matching promises and callbacks; I guess the only wait to get this to work is to wrap the entire thing in a Promise.

Comment: @NickManning No you don't :). `async` functions already return a `Promise`.  Look at my practical example.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to mix and match `async/await` and callbacks, without what feels like a workaround. My use case is that my test contains two lines: the first line is `await myFunc();` and the second line is a function that takes a callback. The test is finished when the callback of the second line is called. I have two choices: not use `await`, or wrap everything in a Promise. I tried to show what I mean here: https://codesandbox.io/s/w78x85wl98

Comment: Ah, I get it. I'd personally wrap the callback-style function in a `Promise` so I can use `async/await` on everything. As I said you can `await` both `Promise` and `async` functions the same. In general, if I have control over the code that I'm testing (I wrote it), I ["promisify"](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) all callback based code I use from external callback-style API's, so the entire asynchronous API of the code I'm working with always uses Promises. If sensibly used, then it obviously makes testing easier as well (by eliminating completely the need for `done`).